# smooth transition with tweenlite doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I have a vector circle and what to do the following:

I 'd like to animate it with tweenlite so it looks like a shockwave of an explosion. At first it fades in (from 0 to .5) and gets scaled and when it reaches half of the total animation time it fades out but it still gets scaled (hope you know what I mean).

Currently it looks horrible because I don't know how to get a smooth transition from part 1 to part 2 with TweenLite. My animation stops when reaching the end of part 1 and suddenly makes a jump to part 2.

Can someone help me out with this problem please? Thank you very much.:)

Total time of animation: .75 sec
total amount of scaling: 5

```
part 1 of 2:

TweenLite.to(blastwave, .375, {alpha:.5, transformAroundCenter:{scale:2.23},
            onComplete:blastScaleFadeOut, onCompleteParams:[blastwave]});


part 2 of 2:

private function blastScaleFadeOut(object:DisplayObject, time:Number = .375, scaleVal:Number = 4.46) {

TweenLite.to(object, time, {alpha:0, transformAroundCenter:{scale:scaleVal},
    onComplete:backgroundSprite.removeChild, onCompleteParams:[object]});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TweenLite** applies an easing function to the tween transition to control the rate of change, and the **default ease is a Quad.EaseOut** (this means the rate of change in the tween will **decelerate** as it approaches the end using a quadratic function). This is why you see such a sudden change (or "jump"), because at the "joining point" of both tweenings (or parts, as you call them), the rate of change is quite different: the first tweening is at its slowest rate because it was reaching the end, while the other is at its quickest rate because it's just beginning.

I'm afraid the only way to really assure that there will be no "jump" (the rate will be the same at the end of part 1 and the beginning of part 2) would be to use a **Linear.easeNone** ease, which means no easing or acceleration (constant speed through the duration of the tween):

```
TweenLite.to(blastwave, .375, 
{ease:Linear.easeNone, alpha:.5, transformAroundCenter:{scale:2.23},
onComplete:blastScaleFadeOut, onCompleteParams:[blastwave]});

//part 2 (put inside function)
TweenLite.to(object, time, {ease:Linear.easeNone, alpha:0, transformAroundCenter:{scale:scaleVal},
onComplete:backgroundSprite.removeChild, onCompleteParams:[object]});
```

But I'd recommend you to play around with the easing functions and their parameters and try to find a combination that suits your needs (Linear.easeNone is a little bit boring).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should rethink how you manage those tweens. You should put the scaling of the sprite to one tween and then divide the alpha transitions into two separate tweens. By default, this won't work in TweenLite, because of it's Tween overwriting policies. However, you can change this either by using `TimelineLite` to chain your tweens, or add `overwrite:OverwriteManager.NONE` property to your tweens. These two solutions work:

Using TimelineLite to chain your tweens:

```
var timeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite();
timeline.insert(TweenLite.to(blastwave, 0.7, {scaleX: 7, scaleY: 7}));
timeline.insert(TweenLite.to(blastwave, 0.35, {alpha: 0.5}));
timeline.insert(TweenLite.to(blastwave, 0.35, {alpha: 0, delay: 0.35}));
```

Or just change the tween overwriting policy:

```
TweenLite.to(s, 0.75, {scaleX: 7, scaleY: 7, overwrite:OverwriteManager.NONE});
TweenLite.to(s, 0.35, {alpha: 1, overwrite:OverwriteManager.NONE});
TweenLite.to(s, 0.35, {alpha: 0, delay: 0.35, overwrite:OverwriteManager.NONE});
```

[About TweenLite's OverwriteManager and tween overwriting.](http://www.greensock.com/overwritemanager/)

On a side note, if you scale your explosion for 0.7 seconds, make the whole alpha in, alpha out process shorter, like 0.55 seconds. Looks better that way. :]

Comment: Thank you very, very much!:) I didn't use TimeLineLite yet. Thanks for that great hint!